# How to include pods in another subproject?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a workspace with one main project, pods and 2 other subprojects.
Those subprojects are not meant to be run independently, they are built into frameworks and linked to main target.
One of subprojects (let's call it SubA) has a dependency, that I added to main podfile.
But since cocoapods 1.0.0 came out, I cannot build SubA, it does not see that imported pod. It gives error on `import` `No such module ...`.
Before 1.0.0 everything worked out of box. And I cannot make it a subpod, because it depends on another subproject, SubA, so keeping in sync all these would be a hassle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` recursive to `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` of sub-project solved the problem.

Comment: Any idea how to do it when the your subproject is a dynamic framework?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Did not deal with stuff for long time.

Comment: You have no idea how much you helped me :o thanks a lot mate !

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
workspace 'Projects.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
    # all the pods go here
    # pod 'Parse' etc.
end

xcodeproj 'Project1.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'

target :Project1 do
  xcodeproj 'Project1'
  shared_pods
end

target :Project2 do
  xcodeproj 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'
  shared_pods
end
```

Comment: `xcodeproj` is deprecated. I tried it with `project`, but it does not see target of that project. Only main one targets.